# String extraction with single quote

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I wish to detect a string with the below if statement, but it gives me the wrong output. I could not detect `ARR`. When I use below if statement, the output will be "wrong". It should go to pass when my input is `ARR`.

My data is in this way, I wish to edit my if-statement instead of editting the way I put my data.

```
['TPA']
['TPI']
['ABC']


if MM[0] == ('\'ARR\'' or '\'ABC\'' or '\'SAC\''):
    pass
else:
    print('wrong')
```

Comment: fix your indentation please

Comment: You don't need escaped single quotes around them. They are stored as strings `if MM[0] == ('ARR' or 'ABC' or 'SAC'):` works fine

Comment: I have edited as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it not the single quote make the output of your code unexpected, it's because you use a wrong if statement.

If you want to check `MM[0]` is either 'ARR' or 'ABC' or 'SAC', you need to use

```
MM[0] == 'ARR' or MM[0] == 'ABC' or MM[0] == 'SAC'
```

or

```
MM[0] in ('ARR', 'ABC', 'SAC')
```

Otherwise, `('ARR' or 'ABC' or 'SAC')` is an expression which always return 'ARR', so

```
if MM[0]==('\'ARR\'' or '\'ABC\'' or '\'SAC\''):
```

returns `True` only if `MM[0]` is 'ARR'. If `MM[0]` is 'ABC', then `if` statement returns `False` and you will see 'wrong' printed.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the result of following part is `"'ARR'"`:

```
>>> ('\'ARR\'' or '\'ABC\'' or '\'SAC\'')
"'ARR'"
```

Basically the `or` operator will return the left operand when both operands are True and here, since all the strings evaluated as True by python the result of your chained `or` operations is the first string.

For getting ride of this problem and as a more pythonic approach you can simple check the membership with the `in` operator and a `set` which has O(1) complexity:

```
if MM[0] in {"'ARR'", "'ABC'", "'SAC'"}
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you're using a dictionary for the check?

Comment: @LPK when there are no colons, its a set.

Comment: Ah okay. Didn't know that. Thank you!

Comment: I have edited as above, I wish to edit my if-statement instead of my data arrangement

Comment: @LPK Please update it to `if MM[0] in ("'ARR'", "'ABC'", "'SAC'")`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `in` for the search.

```
if MM[0] in {"'ARR'", "'ABC'", "'SAC'"}
```

Then, don't escape everywhere with backslashes, it's ugly. If you know your string has single quotes in it, delimit it with double quotes, it will be much more readable.

Comment: I have edited as above, I wish to edit my if-statement instead of my data arrangement

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
MM[0] in ('ARR', 'ABC','SAC')
```

Cheers

Comment: @vermillon please provide more constructive comments! @d-coder, replace the `or`s with a comma.

Comment: There are already valid answers that answer why it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! that is what I actually wanted to put up as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You should put all valid choices in a list, and perform a list membership check like this:

```
wanted = r"'ARR'"

if wanted in [r"'ARR'", r"'ABC'", r"'SAC'"]:
    print("Given value was a member of the list.")
```

The `r` in front of the strings is to denote them as `raw` strings, which denote them as strings with different rules for escaping some literal values in them.

Answer (score 0):

```
MM=['ARR', 'ABC','SAC','WWW','ZZZ']


if MM[0] in ('ARR', 'ABC', 'SAC'):
    pass
else:
    print('wrong')
```

Works just fine. You're overthinking it. You don't have to specify MM is an array, as python can figure that out. You don't have to escape the single quotes either. You aren't trying to match a string `'ARR'`, you're trying to match `ARR`

This works across the string you provided... are you trying to loop through them?:

```
MM = ['ARR', 'ABC', 'SAC', 'WWW', 'ZZZ']
for i in MM:
    if i in ('ARR', 'ABC', 'SAC'):
        print "Winner %s" % i
    else:
        print('wrong')
```

gives

```
Winner ARR
Winner ABC
Winner SAC
wrong
wrong
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I did this as well, but so far I get a wrong output

Comment: Change the position of 'ARR' and it doesn't work anymore

Comment: @LPK Yes, it's because his answer is wrong. `('ARR' or 'ABC' or 'SAC')` is a boolean expression which evaluates to the first truthy value in it, in which case it is `ARR`. So this whole expression gets reduced to `if MM[0] == 'ARR'` constantly, and changing `MM[0]` to something else, like, for instance `ABC`, which seems to be a value we want to test against, will return erroneous results.

Comment: `('ARR' or 'ABC' or 'SAC')` actualy evaluates to `'ARR'`. You would need to make a long if statement if you don't want to use `in`. `if MM[0] == 'ARR' or MM[0] == 'ABC' or MM[0] == 'SAC'`

Comment: @NlightNFotis I actually knew that one. Should have elaborated the problem here to save your time :D

Comment: Time for bed for me, I'm missing the easy stuff. Fixed, thanks guys.

Comment: I have edited as above, but 2nd edited answer give me wrong output

Comment: You've changed your question? What is MM now?

Answer (score 0):

**\'** will make **'** to be a part of a string. ex:

```
>>> str1 = '\'demo_string\''
>>> str1
"'demo_string'"
```

The whole `str1` is **`'demo_string'`**.

If you want to match **`ARR`** or **`ABC`** ...

```
data = 'ABC'
if data in ('ARR', 'ABC', 'SAC'):
    pass
else:
    print('wrong')
```

You can also use *`"`* to quote the string, ex:

```
if data in ("ARR", "ABC", "SAC"):
    pass
else:
    print('wrong')
```

---

If you want to match `'ABC'`, please try:

```
if data in ("'ARR'", "'ABC'", "'SAC'")
    pass
else:
    print('wrong')
```